# Multidimensional json typing

Tags: javascript, typescript, cloudflare

I have the following initial json:

```
let options = {cf: { image: {} } }
```

I need to add new elements inside the images key as per the checks below:

```
  if (url.searchParams.has("fit")) options.cf.image.fit = url.searchParams.get("fit")
  if (url.searchParams.has("width")) options.cf.image.width = url.searchParams.get("width")
  if (url.searchParams.has("height")) options.cf.image.height = url.searchParams.get("height")
  if (url.searchParams.has("quality")) options.cf.image.quality = url.searchParams.get("quality")
```

The problem is that it returns that the type **"fit", "width", "height", "quality"** does not exist in the **options.cf.image** element (example below):

```
Property 'fit' does not exist on type '{}'.ts (2339)
```

I tried to create an interface for **cf.image** with the elements being optional but it didn't work because it returns that the element can be null and it can't because it's a string.

In the end, I need the options to be sent to the **fetch(URL, options)** function, where options is of type RequestInit | Request

My complete code is at https://pastebin.com/fvvBpf1e. It is **Cloudflare's** open source for resizing images https://developers.cloudflare.com/images/image-resizing/resize-with-workers/#an-example-worker

Comment: Can you try to use `url.searchParams.get("fit")` alone and see the output ?

Comment: options.cf.image = url.searchParams.get("fit"); results in The type 'string | null' cannot be assigned to type '{}'.
   Type 'null' cannot be assigned to type '{}'

Comment: This is a typo. You are assigning a value to `options.cf.image.fit` but you forgot a **s** for `images`

Comment: Sorry, I typed in the wrong topic. The right thing is image, it's even like this in my code

Comment: Then please create a working snippet that shows the error

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `let options = {cf: { image: {} } }` defines `options` with the type `{ cf: { image: {}; }; }`, which means TypeScript expects the `image` key to only contain an empty object `{}`.

You can add these keys to your `options` definitions with suitable defaults, or define an interface for `options` that appropriately types it.

For example,

```js
// These may not be suitable defaults, but just to illustrate
let options = { cf: { image: { fit: '', width: '', height: '', quality: '' } } }
```

will compile because typescript knows `cf.image.fit` should exist and has a type.

An interface solution may look like:

```js
interface Options {
    cf: {
        image: { 
            // fit? means this type is `string | undefined` 
            fit?: string;
            width?: string;
            height?: string;
            quality?: string;
        }
    }
}

let options: Options = { cf: { image: {} } }
```

Comment: Yours almost worked. It didn't give me an error in the ifs but it did in the fetch, because the second parameter of the fetch (the options) it expects something like Request or RequestInit. I gave an extends in my main interface but it didn't solve.

Comment: Argument of type 'Options' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Request | RequestInit | undefined'.
   Type 'Options' cannot be assigned to type 'RequestInit'.

Comment: https://ibb.co/HVSnVF2

Answer (score 0):

You posted a link to the documentation of CloudFlare.
Reading it can be a good idea:

[RequestInitCfProperties](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/request/#requestinitcfproperties):

> An object containing Cloudflare-specific properties that can be set on the Request object. For example:
>
> ```ts
> // Disable ScrapeShield for this request.
> fetch(event.request, { cf: { scrapeShield: false } })
> ```
>
> Invalid or incorrectly-named keys in the cf object will be silently ignored. Consider using TypeScript and [`@cloudflare/workers-types`](https://github.com/cloudflare/workers-types) to ensure proper use of the cf object.

You can inspect the desired type in [RequestInitCfProperties source code](https://github.com/cloudflare/workers-types/blob/c0de39ad801dec05dca608ef654888612fd42945/manual-ts/cf.d.ts#L82)

So the correct type of options is:

```ts
interface CloudFlareFetchOptions {
    cf: RequestInitCfProperties
}
```

Comment: I've also tested this, and when I type the "CloudflareFetchOptions" in the options variable, when I do the IF of the fit, width, height and quality it returns: the type 'string | null' cannot be assigned to type '"scale-down" | "contain" | "cover" | "crop" | "pad" | undefined'.

Comment: Yes, TS checks that you pass one of the accepted values. Either make the check that the string you retrieve from the url is one of the accepted values, or cast to appropriate type (if this does not break the fetch call)